# can't set src for flowplayer by jquery .attr

Tags: jquery, ajax, flowplayer

I request a secure link via rest and insert it into flowplayer.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       $.get('rest/movies/1/getmovie', function(data) {
                $('source').attr('src',data);
    });
});
</script>

<div class="flowplayer" data-swf="flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.417">
      <video>
         <source type="video/mp4" src=""/>
      </video>
```

The console shows:

```
<div class="flowplayer is-loading is-mouseover" data-swf="flowplayer.swf" data-ratio="0.417">
  <video class="fp-engine">
     <source type="video/mp4" src="*url*/video/4d90d2bb6bjj84dbf8ccjbfb38778987/514500bb/video.mp4">
  </video>
```

The flowplayer will stay white and the video won't show up.
This is a valid url and I can access the video, when I enter the url directly to the src attribute.

Any idea how I can fix this?

EDIT:
The Console shows there is no connection request to the video-server at all.

EDIT2:

I edited my code to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
       $.get('rest/movies/1/getmovie', function(data) {

           $('.flowplayer video').load(data);


           });
});
</script>
```

Chrome returns:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load 
*url*27c87a2a56e117acf25a7bb1182e122b/5145219f/video.mp4. Origin localhost:8080 is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.
```

Comment: You should check if flowplayer has an api for changing the video source.

Comment: I did but id didn't worked in the end. Is it even possible to load a videofile from another server?